# Create an object's type in Typescript where its keys are derived from an array of strings

Tags: typescript

Given:

```
const keys = ["A1", "B1", "C1"]

const obj = {}

keys.forEach((key) => {
  const subKey = key[0]
  obj[subKey] = key
})

// obj = { A: A1, B: B1, C: C1 }
```

Question: For the given scenario above, how do I declare `obj`'s type?

Something like:

```
type Obj<T in keys> = {
  T: string;
}
```

Comment: Those are *values*, not *types*. That's just an index type `{ [key: string]: string }`.

Comment: You have an array of string literals and the object should only have props with the same literal type something like  `type objType = { A1: 'A1', A2: 'A2' } ` ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe With `{ [key: string]: string }`, you wouldn't be able to have type completion.

Comment: What type completion are you expecting?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes. I'm actually using it for React Native where I have an array of strings that I use for Jest (and I do something like `fs.readFileSync` with those strings), because Jest couldn't handle `ImageRequireSource` properly. I'm creating an object so that files that import assets could simply import from this sort of central asset reference so they can do `<Image source={asset.something} />`, that's why I can't have the generic `{ [key: string]: string }`.

Answer (score 1):

Something close to what you want is possible. Firstly we need to improve on the type of the array. By default the `keys` array will be of type `string[]` this does not help us as we need the string literal types for the string values. This helper function will help with that:

```
function arrayHelper<T extends string>(a: T[]) : T[] {
    return a;
}
var keys = arrayHelper(["A1", "B1", "C1"]); // The type of keys  will be ("A1" | "B1" | "C1")[]
```

Now that we have the string literal types, we can easily define a type based off them :

```
var object = (<T extends string>(o: T[]) => 
{
    const obj: { readonly [P in T]: P} = <any>{}
    keys.forEach((key) => {
    obj[key] = key
    });
    return obj;
})(keys);
```

The type of `object` will be

```
var object: {
    readonly A1: "A1";
    readonly B1: "B1";
    readonly C1: "C1";
}
```

An object that has the original values as keys and the value of the same type as the string literal.

The key is the full value not a substring (it is not possible to perform complex mutations on property names), but this might be something you can live with.